# getting javax.transaction.RollbackException: Prepare: NO vote with Atomikos JTA

Tags: hibernate, jta, atomikos

I am using Hibernate and Atomikos for JTA for one of my proof of concepts.  I am getting a JTA transaction unexpectedly rollback exception, maybe due to a timeout. The exception is:

`javax.transaction.RollbackException: Prepare: NO vote`

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs if a transaction is requested to commit but has already been rolled back due to a timeout. So your assumption is totally right. The solution is to **increase** the **transaction timeout**.

Comment: how can you do that. I have a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282120/change-jta-transaction-timeout-from-default-to-custom

I have tried all options but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout for a transaction using spring configurations, for e.g. by declaring transactional.properties file with value,

```
com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives=100
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name=atomikos-log
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=transaction-logs-dir/
com.atomikos.icatch.registered=true
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=10000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=20000
```