# change jta transaction timeout from default to custom

Tags: jta, atomikos

I am using Atomikos for JTA transaction.
I have following setting for JTA:

```
UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(900);
```

but when my code perform JTA transaction, then if it takes more than 5 minutes (which is default value) then it throws exception:

```
Caused by: com.atomikos.icatch.RollbackException: Prepare: NO vote
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.prepare(ActiveStateHandler.java:231)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.prepare(CoordinatorImp.java:681)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.terminate(CoordinatorImp.java:970)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.commit(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:82)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.commit(CompositeTransactionImp.java:336)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:190)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

it looks like its taking the default jta transaction timeout (even though i am setting timeout explicitely (to 15 minutes/900 seconds).

I tried using following properties in application.properties file however it still takes the default timeout value(300 seconds).

```
spring.jta.atomikos.properties.max-timeout=600000
spring.jta.atomikos.properties.default-jta-timeout=10000
```

I have also tried with below property but no luck:

```
spring.transaction.default-timeout=900
```

Can anyone suggest if I need any other setting? I am using wildfly plugin, spring boot and atomikos api for JTA transaction.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Atomikos documentation](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties):

> **com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout**
>
> Specifies the maximum timeout (in milliseconds) that can be allowed for transactions. Defaults to 300000. This means that calls to UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout() with a value higher than configured here will be max'ed to this value. For 4.x or higher, a value of 0 means no maximum (i.e., unlimited timeouts are allowed).

Indeed, if you take a look at the Atomikos library source code (for both versions 4.0.0M4 and [3.7.0](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/com/atomikos/transactions/3.7.0&path=/Source%20Packages/com.atomikos.icatch.imp/TransactionServiceImp.java)), in the `createCC` method from class `com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp` you will see:

```java
387:   if ( timeout > maxTimeout_ ) {
388:       timeout = maxTimeout_;
389:       //FIXED 20188
390:       LOGGER.logWarning ( "Attempt to create a transaction with a timeout that exceeds maximum - truncating to: " + maxTimeout_ );
391:   }
```

So any attempt to specify a longer transaction timeout gets capped to `maxTimeout_` which has a default value of 300000 set during initialization if none is specified.

You can set the `com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout` as a JVM argument with:

`-Dcom.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=900000`

or you could use [The Advanced Case](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration#The_Advanced_Case_40As_of_3.3_41) recipe specified in the *Configuration for Spring* Section from the Atomikos documentation.

Comment: helped this to solve the timeout issue -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=300000

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved similar problem where configuration in application.yml (or application. properties) of Spring Boot did not get picked up.

There was even a log that I later found mentioned in official [docs](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties#JVM_40System_41_Properties).

However, I added `transactions.properties` file (next to the application.yml) where I set mine desired properties.

```
# Atomikos properties

# Service must be defined!
com.atomikos.icatch.service = com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory

# Override default properties.
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir = ./atomikos
```

Some properties can be set within `transactions.properties` and other within `jta.properties` file.